# how to check the login in jsp

Tags: jsp

This the first time I use jsp, and I'm facing some problems.

I want to know how to check the login if I have two types of login. For example, I have the student and professor. 
When the anyone is logging in it should check if it is a student or a professor to forward her to the right page, ie: the student should go to the take_quiz.jsp page and the professor should go to add_quiz.jsp page.

Could anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways:

1-

using (IF Else)
for your example

if(password for this ID = Password in "Student" table) then Forward him to Take_Quze.pjs
else (
if (password for this ID = Password in "Professor" table) then forward him to proffesor.jsp
else
put error message
)//end else

but it's not effictive way.

--

2-
another ways is use separate login forms for Student and Professor,
in JSP, you can use two directories, for example /professor/logi.jsp for Prof
and /Student/login.jsp for student..

That's all.. :)